# Sending a file to the recycle bin makes its MFT filename change. What if you cut the file and paste into external drive?

Tags: windows, mft

I have read (https://alexsta-cybersecurity.com/what-happens-when-a-file-is-deleted-on-a-windows-system/) that if you have a file and you delete it so it goes to the recycle bin, the MFT entry for that file is changed in that the filename is renamed. But if you use Shift+Delete then the filename is not changed in the MFT database.

What happens to the MFT filename for the file if you instead cut and pasted the file onto an external drive?

Comment: cut and paste does a shift delete for that file, it bypasses the recycle bin. It is removed from the MFT.

Comment: It does indeed act like a shift+del on the source driver, however nothing guarantees it is removed from the MFT. In fact, it will most likely still be in there. MFT will flag the file as deleted and the sectors it occupied will just be marked as free space.